# ZMQ device queue does not load balance properly

Tags: load-balancing, distributed-computing, zeromq

I know that ZMQ offers all of the flexibility to do your own load-balancing.  However I would expect the out-of-the-box broker, about 4 lines of code using the line

`zmq_device (ZMQ_QUEUE, frontend, backend);`

to load balance quite well as the documentation says it does load balance.

> ZMQ_QUEUE creates a shared queue that collects requests from a set of clients, and distributes these fairly among a set of services. Requests are fair-queued from frontend connections and load-balanced between backend connections. Replies automatically return to the client that made the original request.

I have an army of back-end services and yet find that often my front-end clients have to wait several seconds for something that takes < 1/10 of a second in a 1:1 setting (there are same # of client and service machines).  I suspect that ZMQ is not load-balancing properly out of the box - it's sending too many requests to the same service even though it doesn't have bandwidth, etc.

I think this is partly because the services are multithreaded in a way that lets them take up to 10 concurrent requests yet it slows down greatly at near the 10th request even though it can still accept them.  Random distribution would be ideal.  Is there an out-of-the-box way to do this or can it be done in a few lines of code, or do I have to write my own broker from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fwiw issue was the workers were taking on work when they didn't have room for it, issue was not in ZMQ layer per se.